# javascript: how to write a frequency in a class

Tags: javascript

Help:  I am try to use js to write a frequency method in a class, but the error shows the str.length is red line.

Thank you

```
class MyString{

  constructor(str,letters){
    this.str = "Hello World";
    this.letters = "";
  }
  frequency(){
    for (var i = 0; i< str.length; i++){
      var char = str.charAt(i);
      if(letters[char]){
        letters[char]++;
      }else{
        letters[char] = 1;
      }
    }
    return letters;
  }

}

  let txt1 = new MyString("uuuuii.");
  txt1.frequency();
```

the answer should be like  u: 4 i:2

html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
  <script src = "assignment.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You constructor has 2 parameters but you give it only one. Your method returns a value, but you don't use the returned value. I wonder why you make this a class anyway. Why not just a function?

Comment: you should access the class variable using `this` operator e.g `this.str` and `this.letters`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes look how width and height are referenced

Comment: I didn't think you could refer to `this` from inside the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to always refer to the instance:. `this.str`, `this.letters`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer to instance variables using `this`. Also you probably want to return an object rather than string, and you don't need `this.letters`.

```
class MyString{

    constructor(str){
      this.str = str;
    }
    frequency(){
        const freq = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < this.str.length; i++){
            var charAt = str.charAt(i);
            if (freq[charAt]) {
                freq[charAt]++;
            } else {
                freq[charAt] = 1;
            }
        }
        return freq;
    }
}

let txt2 = new MyString("uuuuii.");
console.log(txt1.frequency());
```

Comment: thanks，but  my coursework asked have a property letters which is an object that stores key-value pairs, one for each letter of the text. The keys correspond to the letters and the values, to the number of times the letters appear in the text.  I don't know how to set the letters